# How to open a form in new tab/window in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i wan to open a form in new window. i am following [David Gilbertson
 post](https://medium.com/hackernoon/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202)
 to open new window.
i wrote my form here

```
{this.state.showWindowPortal && (
      <MyWindowPortal>
        <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <img src={this.state.file}/>
      </div>
      </MyWindowPortal>
    )}
```

and i wrote this handle change in my main component. but i am able to make a call to this function.
i have two component

```
class DisplayCard extends React.Component  {}
```

and

```
class MyWindowPortal extends React.PureComponent {}
```

i also tried to write this function in MyWindowPortal but still unable to call this function

```
 handleChange=(event)=> {
  console.log("in image",event)
  this.setState({
    file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
  })
}
```

here is the sandbox url for the same.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-driscoll-wetlw

Comment: what is the error you are getting, can you create a sandbox and share the same

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty i have created sandbox. please check https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-driscoll-wetlw

Comment: @SumanthMadishetty i am getting no error ..just nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why but adding the following lines to `App.js` makes it work

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.setInterval(() => this.setState({}), 500);
}
```

May be The clicks on portal is updating the react state but its not updating the DOM, So, due to that setInterval, it triggers rerender and during that re render its checking the state and unmonting the component.

I cant tell you the exact workaround or why this is happening, will look in to it